# GeoServer NetCDF plugin, read grid_mapping_name="vertical_perspective"

Tags: geoserver, netcdf

I am currently using NetCDF plugin for GeoServer. I would like to know if there is any solution to be able to read a NetCDF with the attribute `grid_mapping_name="vertical_perspective"`.

While debugging I found out in `org.geotools.coverage.io.netcdf.crs.NetCDFProjection`, that only few projections are currently supported (code available here : https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/fe5eac60bcbaabc50af40b75de7bae6f320f09e9/modules/plugin/coverage-multidim/netcdf/src/main/java/org/geotools/coverage/io/netcdf/crs/NetCDFProjection.java#L236)

So I would like to know if any of you dealt with "vertical_perspective" projection while using Geoserver NetCDF plugin? And how did you manage to make it work? Maybe one solution is to override NetCDFProjection class and add "vertical_perspective" projection?

Answer (score 0):

GeoTools does not support a projection named "vertical perspective". The first step would be to add support for it, by writing the necessary code in the `gt-referencing` module, and then to wire it up in the `gt-netcdf` module.

In case you or someone you know can do it, [contribution rules are here](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/main/CONTRIBUTING.md), otherwise, there are [companies that can do it on your behalf](http://geoserver.org/support/).